# nodejs returned unexpected strange output

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
console.log(a,b)
```

Below is the output of my above code

[image]

And when I run this

```
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
   c[a[i]] = b[i];
}
```

But I got BLANK when I do `console.log(c)`

That's so strange, I do a fiddle my logic is fine : http://jsfiddle.net/8m97zk8d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is declared as array and array *should* not have string as key, use object instead. Declare `c` as object.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pk90pm7x/)

```js
var a = ['Child', 'Adult'];
var b = [2, 6];
var c = {}; // Declare as empty Object

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  c[a[i]] = b[i];
}

console.log(c);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(c, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: `Array` is still an `Object`, so it can has string as key for its properties, it just won't count in length.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Right, in this case OP want _object_. And _array_ should not be used as _object_ by assigning string keys.

Comment: Yep, I know that, as I've upvoted this answer, just it may be more clear to say that `array cannot have string as index`.

Comment: @MaySun Array is used to store index and value, although as array is also object, you can add properties on it, but properties are not enumerable, the values can be still accessed using dot or `[]` notation with key. Check http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8m97zk8d/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array c and assigned **attributes** to it. Check out that those attributes are available to log:

```
console.log(c.Child);
console.log(c.Adult);
```

If you want to access them in a traditional way, then redefine `c` as an object:

```
var a = [ 'Child' , 'Adult'];
var b = [2,6];
var c = {};

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
                c[a[i]] = b[i]
            }
console.log(c);
```